# Selection.Find through the document doesn't match the text it's supposed to find

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to loop through the paragraph numbers, match them with their references in the text and automatically create cross references.  The problem I'm running into is that after I find the text, Selection.Text doesn't seem to match what I passed into it half the time (RefNum).  I suspect the problem is in my Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True line, but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it as a newbie at VBA.  Can anyone help me take a look?

```
Sub cross_reference_generator()

Dim RefList As Variant
Dim Ref As String
Dim i As Integer

With ActiveDocument
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    RefList = .GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeNumberedItem)
    For i = UBound(RefList) To 1 Step -1
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        Ref = Trim(RefList(i))
        RefNum = Split(Ref, " ")(0)

        With Selection.Find
            Do While Selection.Find.Execute = True
             .Forward = True
             .Wrap = wdFindStop
             .Text = RefNum
             .Execute

            Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Numbered item", _
                                           ReferenceKind:=wdNumberFullContext, _
                                           ReferenceItem:=CStr(i), _
                                           InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
                                           IncludePosition:=False, _
                                           SeparateNumbers:=False, _
                                           SeparatorString:=" "

            Loop
        End With            
    Next i
End With
End Sub
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have anything to test with, but it seems like some of your lines are out of order.  For example your first call to `Execute` occurs before you set the `.Text` property...

```vb
Sub cross_reference_generator()

    Dim RefList As Variant
    Dim Ref As String
    Dim i As Integer
    
    With ActiveDocument
        Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        RefList = .GetCrossReferenceItems(wdRefTypeNumberedItem)
        
        For i = UBound(RefList) To 1 Step -1
            
            Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
            
            Ref = Trim(RefList(i))
            RefNum = Split(Ref, " ")(0)
    
            With Selection.Find
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindStop
                .Text = RefNum 'set Text before calling execute
                Do While .Execute
                    Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Numbered item", _
                                               ReferenceKind:=wdNumberFullContext, _
                                               ReferenceItem:=CStr(i), _
                                               InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
                                               IncludePosition:=False, _
                                               SeparateNumbers:=False, _
                                               SeparatorString:=" "
    
                Loop
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, that was the right one.  The Do While will need a Selection.Find.Execute to run, but that was exactly the problem!